# Как подвязать 2 сетевые карты к VMware Workstation для одновременной работы двух сетей?

Tags: сеть, vmware

Есть компьютер с двумя сетевыми картами. Как подцепить их так к виртуальной машине, чтобы обе работали одновременно и каждая в своей сети?

Comment: В конфигурацию VM включить 2 виртуальные сетевые карты. Каждую подключить к своему VMNET. Сами VMNET подключить по одной к каждой реальной карте. Всё...

Comment: то есть создать 2 сетевых адаптера в режиме моста...задать нужные айпишники и всё? возможность выхода в инет будет? требуется  передача данных по сети в другую организацию... с виртуалками не работал в этом плане

Comment: *то есть создать 2 сетевых адаптера в режиме моста...задать нужные айпишники и всё?* Если VM в каждой из сетей должна иметь свой собственный адрес, не  связанный с адресом хост-системы - да.